# Redirect entire domain from non-www to www and HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i am trying to redirect  non www to www and http to https

```
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# BEGIN Spark
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END Spark

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

the problem post links redirected to index.php

how to do it like this 
http://domian.com/post-1.html
to
https://www.domian.com/post-1.html

Comment: You need to do this external redirect _before_ the internal rewriting …

Answer (score 0):

works now thinks @cbroe

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# BEGIN Spark
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END Spark
```